# Ecplise, "Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException"

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a tiny game, but i got stuck on this error.
I searched on the internet and all I could find was to use

```
List<Entity> entity = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<Entity>());
```

unfortunately this didn't help me and i tried to work my way around the for loop, but i still couldn't find a fix. Does someone know how I can get rid of this bug.

Handler class

```
public List<Entity> entity = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<Entity>());
public List<Tile> tile = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<Tile>());

public void render(Graphics g){
    for(Entity entity : entity){
        entity.render(g);
    }
    for(Tile tile : tile){
        tile.render(g);
    }
}

public void update(){
    for(Entity entity : entity){
        entity.update();
    }

    for(Tile tile : tile){
        tile.update();
    }
}

public void addEntity(Entity entity){
    this.entity.add(entity);
}

public void removeEntity(Entity entity){
    this.entity.remove(entity);
}

public void addTile(Tile tile){
    this.tile.add(tile);
}

public void removeTile(Tile tile){
    this.tile.remove(tile);
}
```

abstract Entity class (gets extended by every entity)

```
public int x,y,width,height;
public boolean solid;
public Id id;
public Handler handler;
public int velX,velY;
public boolean falling = true;
public boolean jumping = false;
public double gravity = 0.0;
public double health;
public boolean damageable = true;
public long damageTimer = System.currentTimeMillis();

public Entity(int x, int y, int width, int height, boolean solid, Id id,Handler handler){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.solid = solid;
    this.id = id;
    this.handler = handler;
    if(id==Id.Zombie) health=3.0;
    if(id==Id.Player) health=5.0;
}

public abstract void render(Graphics g);
public abstract void update();

public void die(){
    handler.removeEntity(this);
}

public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public int getY() {
    return y;
}

public void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
}

public boolean isSolid() {
    return solid;
}

public Id getId() {
    return id;
}

public int getVelX() {
    return velX;
}

public void setVelX(int velX) {
    this.velX = velX;
}

public int getVelY() {
    return velY;
}

public void setVelY(int velY) {
    this.velY = velY;
}

public Rectangle getBounds(){
    return new Rectangle(x,y,width,height);
}

public Rectangle getBoundsTop(){
    return new Rectangle(x,y-6,width,6);
}

public Rectangle getBoundsBottom(){
    return new Rectangle(x,y+height,width,6);
}

public Rectangle getBoundsLeft(){
    return new Rectangle(x-6,y,6,height);
}

public Rectangle getBoundsRight(){
    return new Rectangle(x+width,y,6,height);
}

public double getHealth() {
    return health;
}

public void setHealth(double health) {
    this.health = health;
}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.checkForComodification(LinkedList.java:966)
at java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.next(LinkedList.java:888)
at Main.Handler.update(Handler.java:26)
at Main.GUI.update(GUI.java:100)
at Main.GUI.run(GUI.java:56)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Line 26 is:

```
for(Entity entity : entity){
```

The bug comes only forth when something gets killed while there are multiple foes. (It happens especially when something gets killed while there is another foe really, really close)

added: Zombie class (the Entity.update(); supposed to execute this classes update() method for each object created with this class)

```
public Zombie(int x, int y, int width, int height, boolean solid, Id id, Handler handler) {
    super(x, y, width, height, solid, id, handler);
}

@Override
public void render(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
}

@Override
public void update() {
    x+=velX;
    y+=velY;

    if(x<=0) x=0;
    if(x+width >= GUI.WIDTH*GUI.SCALE+10) x = GUI.WIDTH*GUI.SCALE-width+10;
    if(y+height >= GUI.HEIGHT*GUI.SCALE+10) y = GUI.HEIGHT*GUI.SCALE-height+10;

    for(Tile tile: GUI.handler.tile){
        if(tile.getId()==Id.Stone){
            if(getBoundsTop().intersects(tile.getBounds())){
                y = tile.getY()+tile.height;
            }
            if(getBoundsBottom().intersects(tile.getBounds())){
                y = tile.getY()-height;
                gravity=0.0;
                falling=true;
                jumping=false;
            }
            if(getBoundsLeft().intersects(tile.getBounds())){
                x = tile.getX()+tile.width;
            }
            if(getBoundsRight().intersects(tile.getBounds())){
                x = tile.getX()-width;
            }
        }
    }
    for(Entity entity: GUI.handler.entity){
        if(entity.getId()==Id.Player){
            if(System.currentTimeMillis()-damageTimer>1000){
                damageable=true;
                entity.damageable = true;
                damageTimer+=1000;
            }
            if(new Rectangle(x-6,y-6,width+12,6).intersects(entity.getBounds())){
                entity.damageable = false;
                if(damageable){
                    if(entity.gravity>=0){
                        setHealth(getHealth()-1.0);
                        entity.falling = false;
                        entity.jumping = true;
                        entity.gravity = -10.0;
                        entity.setVelY((int) entity.gravity);
                    }
                    damageable=false;
                }
            }
            if(getBoundsBottom().intersects(entity.getBounds())){
                if(entity.damageable){
                    entity.setHealth(entity.getHealth()-1.0);
                    entity.damageable = false;
                }
            }
            if(getBoundsLeft().intersects(entity.getBounds())){
                if(entity.damageable){
                    entity.setHealth(entity.getHealth()-1.0);
                    entity.damageable = false;
                }
            }
            if(getBoundsRight().intersects(entity.getBounds())){
                if(entity.damageable){
                    entity.setHealth(entity.getHealth()-1.0);
                    entity.damageable = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(jumping){
        gravity+=0.2;
        setVelY((int)gravity);
        if(gravity>=0.5){
            gravity+=0.1;
        }
    }
    if(falling){
        gravity+=0.3;
        setVelY((int) gravity);
    }

    for(Entity entity : GUI.handler.entity){
        if(entity.getId()==Id.Player){
            if(entity.getY()<y&&!jumping&&getVelY()<=0){ 
                if(entity.getY()<y-10){
                    if(entity.getX()<x){ velX = -3; }else{ velX = 3; }
                    gravity = -10.0;
                    jumping = true;
                    falling = false;
                    velY = (int)gravity;
                } else {
                    if(entity.getX()<x){ velX = 3; }else{ velX = -3; }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(health<=0) die();
}
```

Comment: What is in `entity.update()`? In `Entity` this method is abstract. I suppose that one of implementation changes `entity` collection.

Comment: I've added the answer of your question to the content of my question.

Comment: @NoahSnoeks Your problem is in your die method. You are trying to edit a list `entity` that is currently being iterated. That causes your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in your die method. You are trying to edit a list entity that is currently being iterated. That causes your error.

Instead of modify the list inside it, try to have an auxiliar list that tells you which Entities have died. After all updates, you should delete all this entities.

Comment: If that works, please, accept this answer so everyone can see it.

Answer (score 0):

`ConcurrentModificationException` mean that collection was modified while you iterating over it.

`Collections.synchronizedList` doesn't protect you from `ConcurrentModificationException`.

There is two solution.

1. You can use collection that never throw this exception like `CopyOnWriteArrayList`. But it just hide problem. For example if you iterate over collection of entities and at the same time someone removes one of them you will still process removed entity (which may cause harm like dead zombie still can attack).
2. Design synchronization scheme yourself. There is no common pattern for it, but you should design your code the way that you never modify collection you iterate.